# Error while creating GCP Serverless VPC Connection (“code”: 9) - "Operation failed: Insufficient CPU quota in region."

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, google-vpc

Have tried the following:

- Created it in another project, it worked perfectly fine (but I need it in this specific project)
- Tried various IP ranges like 10.8.0.0, 10.128.0.0, 10.160.0.0 - no use
- Doesn't work either if I change the region to us-central1 (instead of europe-west1).
  See bellow

```
gcloud compute networks vpc-access connectors create mongo-connector \
    --network default \
    --region europe-west1 \
    --range 10.8.0.0/28
```

Getting the following:

```
ERROR: (gcloud.compute.networks.vpc-access.connectors.create) {
  "code": 9,
  "message": "Operation failed: Insufficient CPU quota in region."
}
```

Here is screenshot of my CPUs usage in europe-west1 in this project which says limit 8, current limit usage 0% :
[image]

Also I don't seem to be in  90-day, $300 Free Trial. mode either.

Am I missing something here ?

Thank you for your help